# Apex merge two queries together from salesforce table

Tags: merge, apex, soql

So I have three apex class two child classes and on parent class where I merge the two child objects together on a common field, but I am missing something so help me reach my goal.

```
public class Algolia_product implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, ProductCode FROM Product2];
    }
}

public class Algolia_ProductMedia implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        
        return [SELECT Id, Name, ProductId, ElectronicMediaId FROM ProductMedia WHERE ElectronicMediaGroupId = 'groupId til rigtig billede'];
    }
}
```

And here my parent class where I try merge them together on Product.Id and ProductMedia.ProductId

At the moment I try use a map, but if its better or easier with a List or something else let me know.

```
public class AlgoliaExport_frederik implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Schedulable {    
    
    public class ProductMerged {
        public String Id {get; set;}
        public String Name {get; set;}
        public String ProductCode {get; set;}
        public String ElectronicMediaId {get; set;}

    }
    
    public Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // Create instances of the child batch classes
        Algolia_product productBatch = new Algolia_product();
        Algolia_ProductMedia productMediaBatch = new Algolia_ProductMedia();
        
        // Start the child batch classes and retrieve their results
         Iterable<sObject> productResults = productBatch.start(BC);
         Iterable<sObject> productMediaResults = productMediaBatch.start(BC);
        
        // Create a Map to store the merged results
        Map<String, ProductMerged> mergedProducts = new Map<String, ProductMerged>();

        // Loop through the product results and create a ProductMerged object for each product
        for (sObject productResult : productResults) {
            ProductMerged mergedProduct = new ProductMerged();
            mergedProduct.Id = (String)productResult.get('Id');
            mergedProduct.Name = (String)productResult.get('Name');
            mergedProduct.ProductCode = (String)productResult.get('ProductCode');
            mergedProducts.put((String)productResult.get('ProductId'), mergedProduct);
        }   

        // Loop through the product media results and update the matching ProductMerged object in the map
        for (sObject productMediaResult : productMediaResults) {
            String productId = (String)productMediaResult.get('ProductId');
            if (mergedProducts.containsKey(productId)) {
                ProductMerged mergedProduct = mergedProducts.get(productId);
                mergedProduct.ElectronicMediaId = (String)productMediaResult.get('ElectronicMediaId');
            }
        }

        // Return the merged results as an Iterable of sObject
        return mergedProducts.values();
    }
```

I get this error on both forloops: Loop must iterate over collection: System.Iterable

And return error Illegal conversion from List<AlgoliaExport_frederik.ProductMerged> to System.Iterable

At the end I just want to merge the two tables i fetch in from salesforce, on there commen field. (Its not possible to join tables in Salesforce SOQL so that why I'm trying in apex)